# How to split br, p, div tags into an array using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to split an html string into an array and failing miserably. The code below is stripping out the "<" and ">" but leaving the tag name.

```
var html = 'line 1
 <div>line 2</div>
 <div>line <span class="underline">3</span></div>
 <div>line <stong>4</string></div>
 <p>line <em>5<em></p>
 <br> line 6
 <br /> line 7
 <br/> line 8
 <img src=""/>'

var val = html.split(/<\/?(div|p|br)[^>]*>/igm)
console.log (val)  // ["↵    line 1↵    ", "div", "line 2", "div", "↵    ", "div", "line <span class="underline">3</span>", "div", "↵    ", "div", "line <strong>4</strong>", "div", "↵    ", "p", "line <em>5</em>", "p", "↵    ", "br", " line 6↵    ", "br", " line 7↵    ", "br", " line 8↵    <img src="">↵"]
```

Is there a better way to do this? I realize I could use dom manipulation but I'd prefer to use regex since it's compatible with server-side js

Comment: Depending on what platform you're on, server-side JS can manipulate DOM as well. See [https://npmjs.org/package/node-jquery‎](https://npmjs.org/package/node-jquery‎)

Comment: What’s the expected output?

Comment: You can't parse HTML with regex. I'm pretty sure you can use dom manipulation on the server

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I rather it not have "div", "p" and "br" strings in the output.

Comment: @Chris, I get an error when I visit that link.

Comment: @AbeMiessler Oops. My bad. Something similar is [here](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery), although it might be replaced soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not suggest using regex for this task. But looking at your split regex you're making a mistake pf using a capturing group:

```
var val = html.split(/<\/?(div|p|br)[^>]*>/igm);
```

Make it non-capturing like this:

```
var val = html.split(/<\/?(?:div|p|br)[^>]*>\s*/im);
```

**Reason:** Most of the Javascript engines return a capturing grouped into the result array of the split function call.

**Result:** After applying suggested regex:

```
["", "line 1", "", "line 2", "", "line <span class='underline'>3</span>", "", "line <stong>4</string>", "", "line <em>5<em>", "", "line 6\n", "line 7\n", "line 8\n<img src=''/>"]
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/tM9Qg3

Comment: thanks to this script, but can I ask how to not include empty values in the array? from this: ["","not empty string","","not empty string"]
to this ["not empty string","not empty string"]. What I'm doing now is inserting it again in a new array and excluding empty(""). Thanks

Comment: @blender_noob: I don't want to modify this answer since it was for a different problem. Please ask a new question and I will respond it there.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you're using parentheses and what's inside is being added to the result. This won't work very well, but how about something simpler like this?

```
var val = html.split(/<.+?>/)
```